# React Native - How to map into multiple components?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Consider the following example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(x => {
      console.log(x);
      <Card>
        <AssetExample />
      </Card>
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

Currently the map function is displaying nothing. 
If I remove the `{}` from the map function and the `console.log(x)` I get displayed the 5 Card components.
How can I map into multiple components and functions?
Snack link for those interested: https://snack.expo.io/tEiPsgcjc

Comment: What do you mean by `map into multiple components and functions` ? Removing the `{}` mean that what follow the fat arrow will be returned. If you want to keep it then just wrap your view with `return (<View>...</View>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you see different behavior when removing the `{}`**

`map` returns a new array by iterating through every element in the given array. To make this work, you must return something from the callback function.

To do that, you can either explicitly `return` from `map` or use the implied return syntax:

```js
// Explicit
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return (
    <Card>
      <AssetExample />
    </Card>
  )
})}
```

Or with parenthesis instead of `{}` to use the short hand syntax

```js
// Implied
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(x => (
  <Card>
    <AssetExample />
  </Card>
))}
```

Notice in the shorthand example you cannot `console.log` anymore because everything is returned in this syntax.

**How to return multiple JSX elements from a `map` or component**

You may only ever return one JSX element from a function. What that means is if you need to return several elements, they must be wrapped in another element (like a `View`) so that you are still following the rule.

Here would be an example for your case:

```js
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(x => (
  <View>
    <Card>
      <AssetExample />
    </Card>
    <Card>
      <AssetExample />
    </Card>
    <Card>
      <AssetExample />
    </Card>
  </View>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` expecting a return value. When you have more than one operation (which is in default considered as the returned value), you need to return the value you want using `return`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(x => {
      console.log(x);
      return (<Card>
        <AssetExample />
      </Card>);
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```